# ¿Como puedo utilizar moment.js en pug para formatear fecha a tiempo transcurrido con nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, momentjs, pug

Quiero utilizar moment en la variable time para definir el tiempo transcurrido de una notificacion pero no logro hacerlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen aparece la fecha el formato que quiero cambiar, y eh visto que con moment se puede cambiar pero nose como utilizarlo en el mismo pug para poder darle formato en tiempo transcurrido, por ejemplo: **hace 2 minutos**.

Aqui añado el pug que estoy usando:

```
 ul.dropdown-menu.animation-expand.width-12
                                if notificaciones
                                    li.dropdown-header Últimos mensajes
                                    li  
                                        ul.header-nav.height-9#ul-notificaciones
                                            each val in notificaciones.reverse()
                                                li(style="padding: 0px")
                                                    if val.leido === 0
                                                        a.alert.alert-success(href="#")
                                                            img.height-1.img-circle.dropdown-avatar(src='/img/modules/materialadmin/avatar0.jpg', alt='')
                                                            strong(style='margin-left:10px;')= val.emisorId.nombre
                                                            br
                                                            span= val.mensaje
                                                            br
                                                            small.text-primary= val.titulo
                                                            //em= time
                                                            -let time = val.updated_at
                                                            span.pull-right= time
                                                    else
                                                        a.alert(href="#" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0aa89e;")
                                                            img.height-1.img-circle.dropdown-avatar(src='/img/modules/materialadmin/avatar0.jpg', alt='')
                                                            strong(style='margin-left:10px;')= val.emisorId.nombre
                                                            br
                                                            span= val.mensaje
                                                            br
                                                            small.text-primary= val.titulo
                                                            //em= time
                                                            -let time = val.updated_at
                                                            span.pull-right= time
                                    li
                                        small(style="margin-left:20px;") Opciones
                                    li
                                        a(href=locals.APP_URL+'modulos/usuarios/perfil') | Ver todos los mensajes&nbsp;
                                            span.pull-right
                                            i.fa.fa-arrow-right
                                    li
                                        a#notif_marcar_leidas(href='#') | Marcar todos como leídos&nbsp;
                                            span.pull-right
                                            i.fa.fa-arrow-right
```

Cuando intento poner un script para utilizar el moment me dice que no existe la variable o que no es una funcion, cuando el plugin de moment se esta cargando en todo el frontend desde que se accede a la plataforma.

Si pueden ayudarme a saber como aplicarlo se los agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment, una herramienta poderosa en el desarrollo general de javascript, tiene un metodo para retornar el tiempo que ha pasado solamente pansando como argumento la fecha del pasado.

Te dejo con un ejemplo:

```
moment(FechaAnterior).fromNow();
```

Esto retorna un string, asi que lo almacenaremos en una variable:

```
const timeAgo = moment(FechaAnterior).fromNow();
```

Ahora te dejare un ejemplo completo para que quedes mas claro aun.

```js
const momentAgo = "2014-09-08T08:02:17-05:00"

const timeAgo = moment(momentAgo).fromNow()

console.log(timeAgo)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias intente la solución que me sugirió pero sigo con el siguiente error.

moment is not a function.

Eso me lo arroja al momento que quiero dibujarlo en el pug. Y ya agregue el link de moment en el head del pug. Lo unico que hice es que a la variable time lo iguale a moment(val.updated_at).fromNow() pero sigo en las mismas

Comment: @isaacbustamante Si estas trabajando con backend (nodejs) deberias de usar el manejador de paquetes NPM, instalar el paquete de moment y hacer un require al paquete de moment.

Comment: Me sirvio la recomendacion muchas gracias, el problema ya se soluciono

Comment: @isaacbustamante puedes marcar la respuestas como correcta, esto ayuda a la comunidad con este mismo problema. Saludes!